# FCM Issue: Old Push Coming After Every Reconnection of Internet

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

1. I have cleared the notifications
2. I have disconnected the internet connection and reconnected it after  some time .
3. The old push is still coming to the app.

I have added Firebase SDK for FCM

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
```

The cleared notification should not be shown after reconnection of internet.

Comment: Post code which you have to create Notification.

Comment: Push is handled by system.  As the app is kill  app's push notification receiver will not fire.